# postgreSQL - Daily averages from hourly values by unixtime

Tags: postgresql, average, unix-timestamp

I'm new to databases in general, I'm using postgreSQL (via pgAdmin 4) and I need to extrapolate the daily averages of some atmospheric parameters (in my case the columns are: air_temperature, relative_humidity...) from an hourly table having the date in the unixtime format like this:
[one of my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDcQ5.png)

I want the DAILY averages of temperature and humidity identified in standard date format (the one obtained with "to_timestamp()" like: 2020-07-17) in the usual ascending order by date.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: To give us something to work on, can you provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17 of the data?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I already came up with the solution but I forgot to delete the question, still thank you.

Comment: No trouble at all, @francesco. Just do not forget to delete the question or, better!, share the solution with us. Be well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was easy, this is the solution to my specific case:

```
select date_trunc( 'day' , to_timestamp("dateTime")) , avg(air_temperature) as "avg_T" , avg(relative_humidity) as "avg_RH" , avg(wind_speed) as "avg_WindSpeed"
from table
group by date_trunc( 'day' , to_timestamp("dateTime"))
order by date_trunc( 'day' , to_timestamp("dateTime")) asc
```